# how to use GDataXML or something like DOM parser in swift?

Tags: swift, parsing, dom, gdataxml

how to use GDataXML or something like DOM parser in swift ? (not NSXMLParser)

I need to parse xml for listing data as well to set value in xml on selected node reference.

Any reference of code or link would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already worked on it. and AEXML solved my requirement of xml parsing.

Check further for AEXML [here](https://github.com/tadija/AEXML)